# Be polite with youngers.. hadith

Tags: hadith

In Islam treatment with children are with politeness. how can we give nourishment to them with best etiquettes unless we scold or punish them to do good.. for e.g is there in our Islam to punish child if he/she doesn't pray Salah after they are 10 years old

Comment: So what's your question and how is hadith tag relevant here?

Comment: It is an hadith ' be polite to youngsters'. no more hadith on child upbringing. How can we build our child's character according to islam. If we ain't aggressive on main pillars of Islam. Mere politeness cannot make them a good Muslim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points that I would like to make:

① There are some people in the world who just abuse kids, period. They are not using discipline to guide their behavior towards what is right, rather they are just needlessly harsh or abusive towards their children. Hitting them for no reason, calling them names, humiliating them (lowering their self-esteem), etc. These are the real people who this hadith of mercy and gentleness towards children is aimed at.. because that abuse is unacceptable behavior.

In fact, the Prophet (ﷺ) disapproved of a father who never kissed his children. If even this level of apathy is rejected by the beloved Prophet (ﷺ) then what about those who go well beyond that into physical or psychological abuse? SubhanAllah.

② In the context of teaching children right/wrong and raising them upon Islam, 'politeness' towards children doesn't mean that you are supposed to be soft and lenient on them when it comes to *raising them upon Islam*. Muslim parents should be **firm** in teaching them Islam and the concession on disciplining them (e.g, if they don't pray) is made in this case. However, even that has conditions. (Only used as necessary, not hitting the child on the face, not injuring or bruising them, etc). Still, no element of aggression is allowed or acceptable.